# My App result are totally different in real app than from one in android studio , I don't know why

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

I am learning android development from google course and making the so called tip calculator , while creating its xml layout the result are totally different in real phone, what i see in the layout inspector where we build the layout it is completely fine, but when i run the app in my real device the items are colliding with each other, IDK why, please help me and any one tell me why is this happening, this thig never happened in flutter.
here is my sample of my XML ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CostOfSerivce"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:hint="@string/ServiceCost"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.186" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tip_amount"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Caclculate"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/round_up_switch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="50sp"
        android:text="@string/round_up_tip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/TipGroup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Caclculate"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:padding="20sp"
        android:text="@string/Calculate"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TipGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.414" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HowIsService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AboutSerive"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CostOfSerivce"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.051" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/TipGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/HowIsService"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.088">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Tip20percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amazing_20"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Tip15percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/good_18"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Tip10percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok_10"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </RadioGroup>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here are screenshots of app in layout inspector
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thFHt.png)

here is the screenshot of app in real device
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpyQJ.png)

I don't know why calculate button is colliding in real device while it is perfectly fine in the layout inspector

And yes I have already try changing the text size , but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have given a static height to your button.

Try changing:

```
android:layout_height="77dp"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or try removing the padding `android:padding="20sp"`